# Размещение 3D файлов на форуме

Tags: html, 3d, форум

Подскажите,пожалуйста, какой нужен код, для размещения файлов форматов `.glb`, `.fbx`, `.3mf` на форуме? Типа как размещают просто файлы `[image][/image]`, вот такого плана нужен код и для этих файлов. Я почитала в интернете - пишут, что браузер не распознает 3д файлы...

Comment: Этот вопрос не совсем относится к программированию, но если форум поддерживает вставку iframe то есть возможность

Comment: просмотр моделек?

Comment: Доброго времени суток, файлы загрузятся независимо от их содержания, а вот отображение или точнее регдеринг осуществляется путем библиотек типа WebJL